# How to blur an input field using javascript or react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i am new to programming and i want to blur an input element of type "text".

What i am trying to do?
I have an input element in one react component and thats gets focus using querySelector. Now in other component i want to remove the focus from the same input element.

i have tried using the querySelector with blur method. but didnt work.

Below is my code,

```
 class Popup extends React.PureComponent {
     render() {
         return {
             <OverlayComponent 
                    <input
                        type="text"/>
             </OverlayComponent>
         }
     }
 }

 class OverlayComponent extends React.PureComponent {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.element = document.createElement('div');
     }
     componentDidMount() {
         const input = this.element.querySelector
                       ('input:not([type=button]),
                       input:not([type=submit])
                       :not([type=file]),
                       textarea');
         input && input.focus();
     }

     render() {
         return {
             //something
         }
     }
 }


 class Anothercomponent extends React.PureComponent {
     componentDidMount() {
          const input = document.querySelector
                        ('input:not([type=button]),
                        input:not([type=submit])
                        :not([type=file]),textarea');
          input && input.blur();
     }
 }
```

The input element gets focus in overlyacomponent but doesnt remove focus for input element in AnotherComponent..OverlayComponent and AnotherComponent are seen in same page.

Could someone let me know where i am going wrong. thanks.

**EDIT:**
How can i use setTimeout method in AnotherComponent to remove focus from input element.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this in regular javascript:

```
function BlurTheThing() {
     var TheThing = document.getElementsByClassName(".ClassNameOfTheThing").click(function) {
        TheThing.blur();
     };
}
```

or this if you're not opposed to a little jQuery

```
function BlurTheThing() {
    $(".ClassNameOfTheThing").click(function () { 
        $(this).blur();
    }
}
```

One trick I've used ever since I was shown is, to make sure you're selecting the right thing try changing the border color of the thing you're trying to select with javascript or jQuery as you go. Start with the thing you're clicking:

```
function BlurTheThing() {
    $(".ClassNameOfTheThing").click(function () { 
        // get the element you just clicked
        var TheThingYoureTryingToSelect = $(this);
        // and set it's border to a color that will stand out
        TheThingYoureTryingToSelect.css("border", "thin solid red");
    }
}
```

Make sure the border color changed on the element you expected, then do the same thing again except this time choose that elements' parent (or child or sibling) as necessary:

```
function BlurTheThing() {
    $(".ClassNameOfTheThing").click(function () { 
        // get the parent of the element you just clicked
        var TheThingYoureTryingToSelect = $(this).parent();
        // and set it's border to a color that will stand out
        TheThingYoureTryingToSelect.css("border", "thin solid red");
    }
}
```

And you can stack them and keep going, like `$(this).parent().parent()` or `$(this).parent().sibling()`, etc. In this way you can navigate the DOM and be sure you're selecting the thing you meant to select. Or you can try a `.find(".ClassNameOfTheThing")` and see if that works for you.

Either way, once you're sure you're selecting the thing that you meant to select, the `blur()` should work.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using query selectors?

React is not really built for using Vanilla dom manipulation.

You should use react dom-manipulation, for example, using the state or the props to update the input.

you may also want to use hooks for convinience (this allows you to get rid of the classes and have multiple functions (that each return JSX) in the same context, each with their own 'state').

Comment: i dont want to really complicate using state here meaning passing it from one component to another...if it just could be done with single statement.

Comment: This really should be a comment rather than an answer.